# Will $timeout/setTimeout callback function executes before UI updates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout

The issue is actually happened when I'm writing in AngularJS 1.6.10, but I think `$timeout` is somehow a `setTimout`, so I mentioned both.

Long story short, I have two `div`s to toggle according to a condition using `ng-if`

```
<div ng-if="!vm.isDrillDowned" id="{{vm.segContainerId}}" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
<div ng-if="vm.isDrillDowned" id="{{vm.drillDownContainerId}}" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
```

The code to control the `ng-if` condition is:

```
public renderReport(filters){   
    if (//some condition) {
        reportId = this.drillDownId;
        containerId = this.drillDownContainerId;
        this.isDrillDowned = true;
    }

    if (//some condition) {
        reportId = this.segId;
        containerId = this.segContainerId;
        this.segmentFilter = null;
        this.isDrillDowned = false;
    }
    //Expect $timeout to refresh UI showing one div, then runs this.render()
    this.$timeout(() => this.render(reportId, containerId, filtersCopy));
}
```

**this.render()**

```
public render(reportId: string, containerId: string, filters?: any) {
    const container = document.querySelector(`#${containerId}`);
    this.$window.ThirdPartySDK.renderReportPart(container, /*other parameters */);
}
```

When I debug, **sometimes** when code hits the function inside $timeout, I can see the `isDrilledDown` is changed, but `ng-if` has not already refreshed the view, so `querySelector` can't find the DOM element with regarding `containerId`.

According tho JS's event loop and $timeout/setTimeout's mechanism, I assume `this.render` will only runs after UI is updated, but it's occasionally not true. The same issue happened for `ng-class` too in another place, the element class is not updated when called runs inside $timeout.

I just wonder if this behaviour is possible in some edge cases? All I have searched are saying $timeout/setTimeout will run its callback after UI updates.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if this is not the case. However I am new so I do not have reputation points to comment.

Your function declaration is unique. I was not aware one could or should run code from the parameter of a function.

Perhaps this is just a copy/paste error.

Comment: Do you mean $timeout()? If it is, $timeout accepts the first parameter of function type, what I did is passing a anonymous function. You can define it separately and pass it with the function name.

Comment: No, I was referring to this line `public renderReport(filters?:` . There was no closing brackets. It was probably just a typo though.